# Subquery in SQL Server using Min, Max, Avg

Tags: sql-server

**Task**: write a query to generate the total number of invoices, the invoice total for all of the invoices, the smallest invoice amount, the largest invoice amount, and the average of all of the invoices.

My attempt so far:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT Lines.inv_number) as NumberOfInvoices, 
    SUM(Lines.line_price * Lines.line_units) as TotalSales, 
    MIN(SELECT SUM(Lines.line_price * Lines.line_units) 
        FROM dbo.Lines
        INNER JOIN dbo.Invoices ON Invoices.inv_number = Lines.inv_number 
        GROUP BY Invoices.cus_code) as MinimumSale,
    MAX(Lines.line_price * Lines.line_units) as LargestSale, 
    AVG(Lines.line_price * Lines.line_units) as AverageSale
FROM 
    dbo.Lines 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Invoices ON Invoices.inv_number = Lines.inv_number;
```

I keep getting an error when running. Not sure if I am putting the subquery in the right place.

Comment: What is the error you get? Have you considered simply putting each aggregate into its own sub-query? This may not yield optimal performance but fulfills the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery as below:

```
SELECT   COUNT(A.InvNumber) AS NumberOfInvoices
        ,A.TotalSales
        ,MIN(A.TotalSales)  AS MinimumSale
        ,MAX(A.TotalSales)  AS LargestSale
        ,AVG(A.TotalSales)  AS AverageSale
    FROM (
            SELECT 
                    Lines.InvNumber
                ,SUM(Lines.line_price*Lines.line_units) AS TotalSales
            FROM dbo.Lines INNER JOIN dbo.Invoices 
                ON Invoices.inv_number=Lines.inv_number
            GROUP BY Lines.InvNumber
            ) A
```

You cannot select minimum on sum as SUM itself returns only one value... Also your syntax itself is not correct

Comment: second line should be **SUM(A.TotalSales) AS TotalSales**